# October CMS Backend Model

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

Good day,

I've created a plugin, a model, a controller, and a component.

All that's missing now is the table in the database.

As of 2017-12-18 1820 Taipei time, [this](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugins/updates) URL does not have a document.

So, does this mean I can just call this command?

```
php artisan:make migration create_new_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for creation migration in October cms they are providing **Updates**

you can read article here

reference : https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/updates

you need to define update file in **plugins > updates** directory based on given rules.

then you need to provide information about that update in **version.yaml** then when you fire command `php artisan october:up` or logout and login back to back-end this new updates will be applied.

for creation of `update` files you can get idea from OLctober docs from here.

reference : https://octobercms.com/docs/database/structure

Comment: Okay thank you. I guess the "plugin update file" [link](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/structure) just has the wrong url.